# Как от текущей даты отнять 30 минут?

Tags: javascript

Как отнять минуты от текущей даты?

Comment: Работать с датами через http://momentjs.com/

Comment: Как раз для него мне и нужно :-)
Есть определение разницы между date_start и текущей датой: date_start.fromNow(). А мне нужно от текущей даты отнять 30 минут.

Answer (score 1):

```
var d = new Date();
d.setMinutes(d.getMinutes() -10 );
alert( d );
```

Но лучше почитать [документацию](https://learn.javascript.ru/datetime)

Answer (score 0):

Не оно?

```
var time = moment.duration("00:30:00");
var date = moment();
date.subtract(time);
```

Comment: Нет. У меня следующее: var date_start = moment().subtract(7, "days"); date_start.fromNow(). Тоесть нужно от fromNow() отнять 30 мин, и посчитать разницу между date_start и fromNow()-30мин.

Comment: @ВикторПавлов ну так в вопросе об этом напишите.